# How can I translate --machine argument to systemctl into a unit file?

Tags: systemd, udev, pulseaudio, pipewire

I have this unit file `hdmi_sound_toggle.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs /usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py to switch to the correct sound output
  
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py
```

Then I have a udev rule like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/run_hdmi_sound_toggle"
```

With `/usr/local/bin/run_hdmi_sound_toggle` being:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl --machine=drew@.host --user --now start hdmi_sound_toggle.service
```

Afte I run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --action=change --subsystem-match=drm
```

The file `/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py` runs succesfully. I need the parameters `--machine=drew@.host --user` because I call `pactl` in the script. udev is run as root and so Pipewire/PulseAudio, which is run as a user process (if I get it right), would refuse the connection and the script would fail.

However, I would like to run the systemd unit directly via udev, eliminating the need for `/usr/local/bin/run_hdmi_sound_toggle`. How would I put the `--machine=drew@.host --user` into the unit file so this would work? I tried looking in the docs but I could not figureit out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is not possible, as it is not supported: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2022-January/047336.html